# Chrome Queueing Requests

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

[Chrome Timing View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyzD0.png)

The image above show chrome spends most of the time queuing up the request. I am trying to figure out why that is happening to minimize it.

According to chrome developer documents:

A request being queued indicates that:

1. The request was postponed by the rendering engine because it's
   considered lower priority than critical resources (such as
   scripts/styles). This often happens with images.
2. The request was put on hold to wait for an unavailable TCP socket that's about to free up.
3. The request was put on hold because the browser only allows six TCP connections per origin on HTTP 1.
4. Time spent making disk cache
   entries (typically very quick.)

Number 3 seems to be the most likely problem according to chrome developer documents but I know that only one request is going out at a time so that can't be it. I don't think it is number 1 either because the performance monitor doesn't show a lag from rendering. Maybe it is either 2 or 4 but I don't know how to test that.

[Chrome Performance Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiUMY.png)

I've included a picture of the performance monitor that shows these long tasks where something is happening in the system. These are also a mystery to me and seem related.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: It seems you can disable the disk cache when you open dev tools and that didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Have you ever found an answer for your situation? I have the same issue.. a single requests queues for 2-3 seconds even tho there are no other requests happening..

Comment: @BertMaurau My company had added a virus detection software that was analyzing every packet sent out by the computer. This was slowing down the requests to a crawl. Good luck!

Comment: Oh ok, good to know that that is something as well to look out for! Thanks for replying!